# When I'm running the code in Xcode 7 Beta 3, I am getting a warning as Data argument not used by format string. How to remove this?

Tags: ios, xcode

```
 strTempTracker=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@",
 [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:TABLENAME], 
 [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:COLUMNNAME],
 [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:TABLENAME],
 [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:CUSTOMER_CODE_TRACKER], 
 [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:CUSTOMER_CODE_TRACKER]
 [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:ADDITIONAL_PRIMARY_COLUMN],
 [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:SECONDARY_COLUMN]];
```

Comment: In `initWithFormat`, you are calling only one param using `%@` sign, but in comma-separated list you have many params. So use the same number of `%@` signs in formation string.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking for 1 `arg` and passing multiple, so for each `arg` you need to add `%@`, something like this:

```
strTempTracker=[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@",
                [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:TABLENAME],
                [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:COLUMNNAME],
                [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:TABLENAME],
                [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:CUSTOMER_CODE_TRACKER],
                [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:CUSTOMER_CODE_TRACKER],
                [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:ADDITIONAL_PRIMARY_COLUMN],
                [[resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter] objectForKey:SECONDARY_COLUMN]];
```

---

```
// Cleaner way
NSDictionary *tempDict = [resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter];

strTempTracker = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@, %@",
                  tempDict[TABLENAME],
                  tempDict[COLUMNNAME],
                  tempDict[TABLENAME],
                  tempDict[CUSTOMER_CODE_TRACKER],
                  tempDict[CUSTOMER_CODE_TRACKER],
                  tempDict[ADDITIONAL_PRIMARY_COLUMN],
                  tempDict[SECONDARY_COLUMN]];
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this simple method.

```
NSDictionary *resultDict = [resultSet objectAtIndex:iCounter];
NSMutableString *strTempTracker = [[NSMutableString alloc]init];
[[resultDict allKeys]enumerateObjectsUsingBlock:^(NSString *key, NSUInteger idx, BOOL *stop) {
      [strTempTracker appendString:resultDict[key]];
      [strTempTracker appendString:@","];
 }];
```